# calling Matlab's portfolio optimizer via Python failed

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, portfolio, quantitative-finance

Here I estimated my asset returns and covariances in Python and want to use Matlab's portfolio optimizer to get a portfolio with maximum Sharpe ratio

in Matlab I have a function

```
function pwgt= calculate_portfolio(r0,m,C,lb,ub,target)
p = Portfolio('RiskFreeRate', r0);
p = setAssetMoments(p, m, C);
p = setBounds(p,lb,ub);
p = setBudget(p,target,target);
pwgt = estimateMaxSharpeRatio(p);
```

In Python I have

```
import matlab
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.connect_matlab()
test_mean = matlab.double(mat_mean.values.tolist())
test_cov = matlab.double(mat_cov.values.tolist())
result = eng.calculate_portfolio(0.03, test_mean, test_cov, -1, 1, 1)
```

Where test_mean is a 5*1 pandas series, test_cov is a 5*5 covariance matrix (stored as pandas dataframe).

However, when I call the function in Python, the error goes as:

```
MatlabExecutionError: 
File /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/optim/optim/linprog.m, line 158, in linprog
File /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/private/mv_estimate_lower_bound.p, line 0, in mv_estimate_lower_bound
File /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/private/mv_optim_transform.p, line 0, in mv_optim_transform
File /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/estimateFrontierLimits.m, line 70, in estimateFrontierLimits
File /Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/toolbox/finance/finance/@Portfolio/estimateMaxSharpeRatio.m, line 33, in estimateMaxSharpeRatio
File /Users/Michael/Documents/MATLAB/calculate_portfolio.m, line 6, in calculate_portfolio
LINPROG requires the following inputs to be of data type double: 'b','LB'.
```

How do I solve this problem.

Comment: no idea where `'b'` comes from, but your matlab-signature looks like this: `calculate_portfolio(r0,m,C,lb,ub,target)` - there is a lb in it (casing different) - you provide a `1` from python, not `1.0` so it might get inputted as int instead of double. -just guessing, luck wiht resolving it.

Comment: Seems that it worked.
No idea why it happened.